# Connect Raspberry Pi 4 GPIO output pins to Arduino Uno

Tags: gpio, arduino, output

I want my Raspberry Pi4 to give 4 unique outputs, not necessarily at the same time, which will be four different inputs to the Arduino Uno.

I want to know how to proceed as I think by connecting them directly will result in one of my devices to blow up or be damaged. Do I need to add some resistance circuit in between and if yes, then what resistance should I use.

I am working on a machine learning model which I hope generates an interrupt when a detection is made and sends it to the Arduino Uno which performs further actions.

Please help.

Comment: Try writing in paragraphs (spell check would help too). You NEED to add detail of what you propose.

Comment: if the UNO uses 5v GPIO, then, yes, you do NOT want to connect it directly. use a "logic level shifter" between them

Answer (score 0):

For me the safest/easiest/cheaper/quicker way to do it is with a level shifter like this:
https://thepihut.com/products/pololu-logic-level-shifter-4-channel-bidirectional
If you look in there you can find shifters with more channels.